# Errors, warning, notices with a cross to hide them using Jquery. How to extend the core message class in a right way to achieve this?

Tags: magento

I want my error, warning, notification messages on frontend to extend a bit. So,

I need to override

> Mage_Core_Block_Messages

class's

```
    public function getGroupedHtml()
{
    $types = array(
        Mage_Core_Model_Message::ERROR,
        Mage_Core_Model_Message::WARNING,
        Mage_Core_Model_Message::NOTICE,
        Mage_Core_Model_Message::SUCCESS
    );
    $html = '';
    foreach ($types as $type) {
        if ( $messages = $this->getMessages($type) ) {
            if ( !$html ) {
                $html .= '<' . $this->_messagesFirstLevelTagName . ' class="messages">';
            }
            $html .= '<' . $this->_messagesSecondLevelTagName . ' class="' . $type . '-msg">';
            $html .= '<' . $this->_messagesFirstLevelTagName . '>';

            foreach ( $messages as $message ) {
                $html.= '<' . $this->_messagesSecondLevelTagName . '>';
                $html.= '<' . $this->_messagesContentWrapperTagName . '>';
                $html.= ($this->_escapeMessageFlag) ? $this->htmlEscape($message->getText()) : $message->getText();
                $html.= '</' . $this->_messagesContentWrapperTagName . '>';
                $html.= '</' . $this->_messagesSecondLevelTagName . '>';
            }
            $html .= '</' . $this->_messagesFirstLevelTagName . '>';
            $html .= '</' . $this->_messagesSecondLevelTagName . '>';
        }
    }
    if ( $html) {
        $html .= '</' . $this->_messagesFirstLevelTagName . '>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

to extend the html and put a cross in the message box and implement Jquery. logic: on click close hide error box. So customers can upon click hide the box.

I believe this class doesn't have any template file and the html it is rendering from the this block class itself as I can see in getGroupedHtml() method.

So, I am going to override this method and add more html.

Also, I want to do this only for one theme and not in Admin

What is the better way to achieve this?

Please suggest me something.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could accomplish this without overriding anything and by just going for JavaScript (jQuery) only.

Here is a simple script that should do the job.

```
var messages = jQuery("ul.messages li[class$='-msg']");

messages.each(function(){
    var message = jQuery(this);
    message.find('span').append('<span class="close">X</span>');
});

messages.on('click', function(){
    var message = jQuery(this).closest("li[class$='-msg']");
    message.hide();
});
```

The script adds a 'X' to the end of every message and removes (hides) the message when it's clicked.

The only thing left to do is to give the cross (span X) some styling.
You could place this in your footer template for the correct theme.